# Every other line is blank when copying an HTML document and pasting it as plain text

Tags: linux, windows, html, clipboard

When I copy a text from an HTML document (e.g. from Firefox, Thunderbird, Internet Explorer...) and paste it as text then after every HTML paragraph (`<p>`) an empty line is inserted.
This also happens when I export the HTML document as text.

It often happens that an HTML document has every line marked as a separate paragraph.
I frequently receive e-mails formatted this way and I think that they come into existence by pasting a plain text into an HTML e-mail under certain conditions.

### Example

How does the HTML document look like:

```
line 1
line 2
```

How does its HTML code look like:

```
<p>line 1</p>
<p>line 2</p>
```

How does the paste into text or export as text look like:

```
line 1

line 2
```

Is there a way how to avoid the inserted empty lines without need to post-process the text document?

The behaviour was observed both on Linux (X Org) and Windows.

Comment: The example output you gave is wrong.  For the given example HTML code it _should_ put a chunk of whitespace in between the lines. (to separate the paragraphs).  What are you pasting this in to? Is it actually putting a real blank line in (where you could type text) or is it just a whitespace gap?

Comment: @techie007: I must admit that the example is a simplified HTML document and I did not test this simplified form. I am going to test it. --- The blank lines are inserted probably during any paste into a plain text format. I have tested a while ago: in Ubuntu 12.04.3 `gnome-terminal`, `gedit` and in Windows XP Notepad. --- It puts a real empty line in. I.e. after `line 1` there are two newlines instead of one.

Comment: It does it for myself as well.  It's the way it's interpreted by the browser, clipboard and/or the paste target.  Again, it's normal, there is supposed to be a blank line between paragraphs, so it's doing what it should. From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp) "Note: Browsers automatically add an empty line before and after a paragraph."

Comment: @techie007: Right now I have tested the HTML code from my question. I saved it as `test.html`, opened in Firefox in Ubuntu 12.04.3, there I exported it as text into `test-export.txt` and here is the hex dump: `od -tx1 test-export.txt --- 0000000 6c 69 6e 65 20 31 0a 0a 6c 69 6e 65 20 32 0a 0a`. The exactly same result is when I copy from Firefox and paste into `gedit` or `gnome-terminal` or anything what accepts plain text. You can see that every paragraph is followed by two newlines (`0a`) instead of one.

Comment: @techie007: Ok, I was thinking that this behaviour is probably defined but I would like to know if there is a simple way how to change or override it because I often receive e-mails formatted this way.

Comment: The browsers are following standards, to have it not follow those standards you need a non-standards-compliant browser.  Which finding a browser that doesn't follow the HTML1.0 standards is going to be tough if not impossible.  Unfortunately you may be best off just getting a text editor with a blank-line removal add-on and post-process it (as you suggest).

Comment: HTML emails usually are sent with both a plain-text and html version, and a reader like Thunderbird can be set to display the plain text rather than the html.  You may find that copying from the plain text version has a format you prefer.

Comment: @mgkrebbs: Thanks for the tip! This could be one of the answers here! In the last e-mail with the problem the plain-text variant does not have the doubled end-lines. This makes me wonder even more - Why an e-mail client makes paragraphs from the lines? Why does not it use `<br>`? In this case it was probably MS Exchange.